# I can not make db2start work on command line

Tags: db2

"The requested command or operation failed because the user ID does  not have the authority to perform the requested command or operation.  User  ID: "DB2INST3"." So What I can do with my problem ?I can't connect my db2 database.

Comment: Talk to your DBA, and have him grant you the authority to run db2start.

Comment: Which instance are you trying to start? you are executing the command with db2inst3, but this user could not have privileges if the instance is db2inst2 or db2inst1

Comment: I am the DBA and I gave db2inst1 root access as well. Same error. No user can run any db2 command, like db2, db2set, db2start, etc.